# What can i do to click a html checkbox and change the content of a html input?

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

Like i've said in the question... Is there a way to click the checkbox and that link will change to `http://youtu.be/kffacxfA7G4`?

[image]

Example of code:

```
<div class="embed-code">
        <textarea rows="" cols="">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4</textarea>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          Short URL</label>
      </div>
```

I am thinking this can be done with javascript/jquery...

Is anybody using this? Thanks in advance...

**EDIT :**

I've managed to do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tpLfS/

```
$('#myCheckBox').click(function(){ var myLink = $('#myTextarea');

if ($('#myCheckBox:checked').val() !== undefined){ //checked
myLink.val(myLink.val().replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4','http://youtu.be/kffacxfA7G4'));}

else { //not checked    
myLink.val(myLink.val().replace('http://youtu.be/kffacxfA7G4','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4'));}

})
```

Can it be done easily?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about how to change the content on click, or are you asking about how to generate a shortened URL?

Comment: yes, i was asking how to change the content on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In query its pretty simple: first you need to give your checkbox and textarea an id:

```
<textarea rows="" cols="" id="myTextarea">...</textarea>
<input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" />
```

then you add the javascript part (in my example with jQuery):
Im not sure how you want to change it. I think you just want to remove the "watch?v="

```
$('#myCheckBox').click(function(){
  var myLink = $('#myTextarea');

  myLink.val(myLink.val().replace('watch?v=',''));
})​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E3f9M/

Comment: But how can i change that with a predefined url like `http://youtu.be/kffacxfA7G4` i mean not just replace that part from the initial url ? Also i noticed in your example that if i uncheck the checkbox again it remains the second url.

Comment: i just showed the concept of how its be done, you can just save the previous url in an variable and then restore on uncheck. And for the url: You can do it with simple String operations (like split, substring, length) or for more complex examples you should take a look at regular expressions (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: Thank you. Based on your example i managed to do what i was looking for. Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/tpLfS/ Can you please look at it and tell me if it can be optimized?

Comment: “Here is the code: jsfiddle.net/tpLfS Can you please look at it and tell me if it can be optimized?” — Obviously it’s up to @XzenTorXz, but Stack Overflow isn’t really intended to provide you with people to work on your code with you. It’s intended to collect questions and answers that will be useful to people who find them in the future.